# Where to download pdftex 1.40.4

Tags: pdftex

In the readme of the microtype package page7, it is said that pdftex >= 1.40.4 is recommended. I have miktek on windows xp and my version is :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
```

Where can I get the latest version ?
I have just updated my miktex distribution and there is no more updates to be applied.

Comment: You are on the safe side since your installed version is more recent than the required one: 14 > 4.

Comment: As AlexG already said, your `pdfTeX` is the most recent. If you want to make sure your MikTeX is up-to-date, follow the instuctions [here](http://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex) to update your MikTeX distribution.

Comment: Ha ok, the 4 in 1.40.4 is not for 40 but just 4.

Comment: @Philipp Obviously the number **1.40.14** is *larger* than **1.40.4**, hence this is a more recent version as the version numbers are always counting up.

Comment: @Philipp The notation for versions is similar to decimal, but it isn't the same: version 3.10 is later than version 3.2; each number is examined separately.

Comment: 1.4014 ist the `latest` stable version of pdftex, dated 2013/5/1.

Answer (score 3):

Your installed version 1.40.14 is more recent than the recommended version 1.40.4 and can safely be used with `microtype`. As egreg pointed out, each number part in the version string (major.minor.revision) is examined separately.